# How to block Windows-shutdown in PowerShell under Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I have to run a PowerShell script which requires a long time to complete.

During this time I want to prevent the computer running it from being shutdown down by the user.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Even if the user wasn't put in control of this by Windows, you can never prevent e.g. a sudden loss of power. Generally, I'd suggest trying to move things around so that the (thing that takes a long time) can be done at some other time or broken up.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Workflows in PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psworkflow/about/about_workflows)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work (untested):

```
$File = "$env:SystemRoot\system32\shutdown.exe"
$PreviousAcl = Get-Acl $File

$Principal = "domain\user"
$Right = "Read"
$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Principal,$Right,"Deny")

Try {
    $Acl = Get-Acl $File
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Rule)
    Set-Acl $File $Acl 
}
Catch {
    Write-Error "ACL failed to be set on: " $File
}


# yourscript here


Try {
    Set-Acl $File $PreviousAcl 
}
Catch {
    Write-Error "ACL failed to be set on: " $File
}
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/52x3s2/create_deny_permissions_on_folders_via_powershell/d7o17wu/

Comment: This would only work if the user is trying to shutdown the computer by using that file. If they use the start menu or press the power button it will still shutdown.

Comment: Thats the problem, the user should be able to click on shutdown, the computer could also lock and go to the shutdown-procedurre, but it shouldn't turn off until the script ended.

Comment: My understanding is that shutdown.exe is called even when using the start menu option (however that is anecdotal and untested). If true, removing the user ACLs from that .exe will prevent them from completing a shutdown. I don't have anywhere to test it right now unfortunately.

Comment: @R.Christes - all you'd achieve here is to annoy your users unless/until they learn that holding down the power button for four seconds causes a (hardware initiated) power off. From that point onwards, you're script will likely never get a chance to finish (because the user, understandably peeved, either uninstalls your script or always powers off using the power button)

Comment: I agree, a better approach would be just to inform the user that they should not interrupt the script by shutting down and have a way of tracking whether or not the script finished.